# Clone windows hard disk and resize ntfs partitions from linux

Tags: windows, disk-space, clone, dd, ntfsresize

I have a 500gb hard disk with two main NTFS partitions, one for a Windows OS and the other for data for use by that OS as well as the boot partition at the beginning of the disk. The data partition is mostly empty but the OS partition is almost completely full. The OS is running extremely slowly as it has run out of room.

I have a new 480gb SSD, I'd like to clone the existing hard disk onto the new SSD but while doing so increase the size of the OS partition and decrease the size of the data partition.

Both the hard disk and the SSD are currently connected to a Linux machine and if possible I'd like to do the operation from there, but I can also boot into the Windows OS if that is easier.

I am not sure what the correct steps are to do this transfer. My current thinking is t DD across 480gb of the data on the 500gb drive. Then delete the data partition, resize the OS partition and then create a new NTFS partition and mount both the new and the old data partitions and CP the data across.

Would this work? And is there a better way? Note, windows will not let me resize the OS partition as the data partition follows on immediately from it on the current disk.

Answer (score 1):

Don't copy partition from hdd to ssd with `dd`. It's likely they have different sector size. Result will be misaligned partition (without proper `seek=N` blocks) and slow data transfer. And `dd` will waste you time coping unused filesystem blocks from data partition.

**Just copy files, not partition.**

Create ntfs partition on ssd.
Copy files from data partition to ssd partition, delete data partition on hdd, resize os partition, create new data partition, copy files back from ssd.

Better do it from windows to preserve ntfs specific data like files owner and ntfs alternative streams.

If it's laptop or you have UPS as alternative you may shift start of data partition and then resize os partition in-place with GParted Live-CD.

**To clone hdd partitions to ssd**
Filesystems on partitions you want to copy must be offline (not mounted).
Download and boot from GParted live CD or USB or install gparted package on you linux system.
Copy MBR Bootstrap code from hdd to ssd with

```
dd if=/dev/hdd_dev_name of=/dev/ssd_dev_name bs=446 count=1
```

Run GParted GUI program and copy and resize partitions from hdd to ssd manually preserving original order of partitions. Check  windows boot partition copy has boot flag on.

https://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dhelp-manual#gparted-copy-and-paste-partition

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right about the sector size. I also want to move the OS and boot partition onto this drive. Can I safely do that from the system the OS is running on itself? This is the only windows system I have access to.

Comment: You wanna clone all partitions from hdd to ssd and then boot windows from ssd?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I want to migrate the HDD to the SSD, which is smaller. I am happy to delete the data partition when cloned, create a new partition and copy the the data across again. I just don't know how to do the first bit.